# I want to know how to do.(on Python, use twitter api)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

sorry, Ican understand English just a little.
In windows10、64bit,And python3.7.
I want to know how to separate the number of likes and retweet.
And if the tweet has alot of likes and retweet,output txtfile by wordcloud 
I know how to collection deta of tweet,but I don't know how to separate tweet.
how do I do?

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad/vague, and off-topic. _Or I can't?_ That is certainly feasible, but as it stands your question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are several YouTube video's/ blogs to help you, ask questions that you can't find anywhere . https://youtu.be/dQG4mkD5Nd4.  Try seeing this video. Even if this is not helping please help yourself in Google/YouTube search

Comment: Sorry,AMC.I change question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Requests library: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

1. Make HTTP request to Twitter’s API that gives you the data you want
2. Process the data
3. To write your output to a txt file, use

```
file1 = open("myfile.txt","w") 
file1.write(your_data_as_text)
```